# Maven module architecture issue

Tags: maven, architecture, dependencies, pom.xml, parent

I'm trying to design a microservices platform using Spring Boot and Maven as dependency manager.

This is the architecture that I'm trying to implement:

MainFolder

```
 - core/
     - pom.xml
     - dep-core/
        - pom.xml //core module as parent
        - src/main/...
 - cfm/
     - my-cfm-one/
        - pom.xml //core module as parent
        - src/main/...
     - my-cfm-two/
        - pom.xml //core module as parent
        - src/main/...
     - ...
 - pfm/
     - my-pfm-one/
        - pom.xml //core module as parent and import my-cfm-one as dependency
        - src/main/...
     - my-pfm-two/
        - pom.xml //core module as parent and import my-cfm-two as dependency
        - src/main/...
     - ...
 - ms/
     - my-ms-one/
        - pom.xml //core module as parent and import my-pfm-one and my-pfm-two as dependencies
        - src/main/...
     - ...
```

My issue is related to the dep-core module.
When I set module core as parent of one cfm, I can't access to the classes defined into dep-core module ( that is imported into core ( parent ) module )

This is the pom of the core module ( I omit some parts to shorten )

```
    ...
    <groupId>it.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>core</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        ...
    </properties>


    <modules>
        <module>dep-core</module>
    </modules>

    <!-- I also tried ( with and without <module> tag )
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>it.test</groupId>
                <artifactId>dep-core</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    -->
</project>
```

This is the pom of the dep-core module

```
    ...
    <groupId>it.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>dep-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>dep-core</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>it.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        ...
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>
        ...
    </repositories>
</project>
```

And this is the pom of one cfm module

```
    <groupId>it.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>search-cfm</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>search-cfm</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>it.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!--SPRING DEP-->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Could anybody give me the right way to design my architecture and solve my issue?

I also added sample project to github in order to see the issue.

https://github.com/jayturchi/test-maven-architecture

Comment: Can you please make a github project of this example structure only pom file etc.

Comment: Sure, please see edit

Answer (score 0):

in order to inherit a dependency (dependency will be in your classpath so you can access its classes) from your parent POM the dependency has to be declared as a dependency of the parent POM; so to have your dep-core as a dependency in parent POM, Just declare it as a male does not make it a dependence. 
You have a problem because you cannot declare deep core as a direct dependency of your core since deep-core POM is child of core POM. That cause a circular dependent that prevent maven from compiling your core. 
To solve the issue you need an intermediate POM inheriting from core and with deep-core as a dependency. Let's call this poem wrapper.
Now You can declare wrapper as parent pom for your leafs projects (cfm and pfm).

I post the corrects POM for core, wrapper and cfm-one.

core.pom

```
  <groupId>it.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-cfm-one</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>my-cfm-one</name>

       <parent>
            <groupId>it.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>wrapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <relativePath>../</relativePath>
        </parent>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
```

wrapper.pom

```
  <groupId>it.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>wrapper</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>it.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>it.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>dep-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

and finally cfm-one

```
    <artifactId>my-cfm-one</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>my-cfm-one</name>
    <parent>
    <groupId>it.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>wrapper</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <relativePath>../</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
 <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```